# ¿Cómo cambio los estilos CSS cuando la pantalla muestra un div en concreto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

**SOLUCIONADO**

[Solución aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/445665/224052)

Mi Index, es una full page, donde cada section es exactamente 100vh de height. He creado un script que hace que si hago scroll, mi web se pasa a la otra section de golpe.

Estoy añadiendo unas barras en el lateral, que aumentan o disminuyen para indicar si estoy en una section u otra. Me gustaría hacer que si por ejemplo estoy en la section #home, la primera barra es más larga, y si hago scroll a la section #about, la primera barra se encoge y la segunda se hace más larga.

He usado esta librería para el efecto de scroll: https://github.com/fabeat/responsive-fullpage-scroll

**Añadido:**

Ahora mismo el scroll me sigue funcionando, sin embargo, al hacer scroll no se "amplia" ninguna `a`, sin embargo al llegar a la tercera section se amplían todas:

Aquí os dejo el código:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var fps = new FullPageScroll('wrap', {
            mediaQuery: 'screen and (min-width: 800px)',
            goToTopOnLast: false
        });
        fps.onslide = function (e) {
            console.log("Slide " + (e.target.currentSlide + 1) + " of " + e.target.slides.length);
            document.querySelectorAll("#lineas a").forEach((link, index) => {
                if (index === e.target.currentSlide) {
                    //añado estilos para indicar que está activa
                    $("#lineas a").addClass('activo');
                } else {
                    //elimino estilos
                    $("#lineas a").removeClass('activo');
                }
            });
            
        }
        document.querySelectorAll('a.top').forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                fps.goToFirstSlide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```css
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
}

#wrap section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#lineas
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 0px;
}

#lineas a
{
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff42e;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#lineas .activo
{
    width: 88px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <section id="home">...</section>
    <section id="about">...</section>
    <section id="work">...</section>
</div>


<div id="lineas">
    <a href="#home" class="first activo"></a>
    <a href="#about" class="second"></a>
    <a href="#work" class="third"></a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fabeat/responsive-fullpage-scroll@v1.0.3/dist/fullpage-scroll.js"></script>
```

El efecto de scroll funciona perfectamente pero no se me ocurre como hacer el efecto mencionado. Es un proyecto hecho con Django.

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: He asumido que estás usando [esta librería](https://github.com/mverissimo/FullPageScroll) para crear el fragmento. Si no es así, por favor pulsa en [edit] y añade la que estás usando para poder reproducir tu escenario fielmente.

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida. La sección de [ask] no viene mal leerla, pero tu pregunta ya está bien expuesta

Comment: @PabloLozano se me olvidó añadirla, perdón, la librería que usé es esta https://github.com/fabeat/responsive-fullpage-scroll

Comment: Parece un clon de la que encontré, los métodos y propiedades son casi iguales. Mi respuesta debería seguir funcionando, creo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es tan complicado, solo tienes que eliminar la clase `activo` de todos los enlaces y usar el índice de la sección actual (ya lo tienes en `e.target.currentSlide`) para agregarla al que corresponda:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Obtener todos los enlaces en una lista de nodos
    let lineas = document.querySelectorAll('#lineas a');

    let fps = new FullPageScroll('wrap', {
        mediaQuery: 'screen and (min-width: 600px)',
        goToTopOnLast: false
    });
    fps.onslide = function (e) {
        // Eliminar clase en todas las líneas
        lineas.forEach(linea => linea.classList.remove('activo'));
        // Agregar clase a elemento actual
        lineas[e.target.currentSlide].classList.add('activo');
    }
    // Agregar evento a los enlaces
    lineas.forEach((linea, x) => {
        linea.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            // El enlace hace scroll y afecta a la función .goToSlide()
            e.preventDefault();
            // Seleccionar sección por índice de enlace que recibió clic
            fps.goToSlide(x);
        });
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('a.top').forEach(function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            fps.goToFirstSlide(0);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
}

#wrap section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrap section:nth-child(1) { background:#800; }
#wrap section:nth-child(2) { background:#080; }
#wrap section:nth-child(3) { background:#008; }

#lineas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 0px;
}

#lineas a {
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff42e;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#lineas .activo
{
    width: 88px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <section id="home">...</section>
    <section id="about">...</section>
    <section id="work">...</section>
</div>


<div id="lineas">
    <a href="#home" class="first activo"></a>
    <a href="#about" class="second"></a>
    <a href="#work" class="third"></a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fabeat/responsive-fullpage-scroll@v1.0.3/dist/fullpage-scroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Me funcionó perfectamente! Aún tengo mucho camino que recorrer en este mundo de la programación.

Comment: Me sabe fatal pedir ayuda y preguntarte... estoy intentando hacer también que al hacer click sobre los elementos `a`, haga también esa función de scroll y de ampliación de las lineas. Supongo que tendría que crear un script similar sin embargo añadiendo un `if(lineas.is(':active')) {`

Comment: @MiguelPayá, edité la pregunta para escuchar clic en los enlaces, revisa si funciona; me basé en [este ejemplo](https://codepen.io/fabeat/pen/EzxEGe), llegando desde en enlace que proporcionaste para la documentación.

Comment: no del todo, si que es cierto que hace scroll al hacer click, pero, por ejemplo ahora mismo tengo 3 sections y al hacer click en el tercer `a`, baja incluso más abajo de mi tercer section, dónde no hay nada

Comment: @MiguelPayá, solo faltaba evitar el comportamiento "normal" de los enlaces con `e.preventDefault();`, ya funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Miraré a ver que hace eso de `preventDefault();` un saludo y muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si he acertado con la librería que estás usando podrías hacer algo como

```js
fps.onslide = function () {
  document.querySelectorAll("#lineas a").forEach((link, index) => {
    if (index === fps.currentSlide) {
      //añado estilos para indicar que está activa
    } else {
      //elimino estilos
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar, me da varios errores

Answer (score 0):

Te doy unas funciones muy útiles para detectar cuando un elemento entre al **viewport** del usuario.

Función para detectar el desplazamiento de un elemento:

```js
offset(e) {
    let top = 0;
    let left = 0;

    if (e.offsetParent) {
      do {
        top += e.offsetTop;
        left += e.offsetLeft;

      } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }
    return {
      top: parseInt(top),
      left: parseInt(left)
    }
  }
```

Función para detectar el alto del **viewport**:

```js
viewport() {
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;

    if (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined') {
      x = window.innerWidth
      y = window.innerHeight
    }
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined'
     && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
      x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      y = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else {
      x = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      y = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
    }
    return {
      width: x,
      height: y
    }
  }
```

Función para detectar el *scroll top* en el navegador:

```js
 scrollTop() {
    let s = 0;
    if (window.pageYOffset) {
      s = window.pageYOffset;
    }
    else {
      s = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return s;
  }
```

Ahora puedes mediante el evento `scroll` hacer esto a un elemento

```js
if (e.getBoundingClientRect().top > 0 && ( (scrollTop() + viewport().height) - offset(e).top ) > 0) {

  // Aquí tu código para modificar esos estilos, al ser visible para el usuario el elemento (cuando entre al viewport)

}
```

Suponiendo que `e` es ese elemento al que deseas modificar los estilos.

Te adjunto [aquí](https://github.com/josbert-m/gravity/blob/master/src/js/main.js) el código de, una librería hecha por mi que tiene todas estas funciones, espero te sirva

**NOTA:** el método `getBoundingClientRect()`, que uso al final, es nativo de javascript

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Le echaré el ojo!

Comment: Recibo una alerta de `ilegal return statement`

Answer (score 0):

He añadido las lineas que me has comentado Pablo y solamente aumenta el tamaño de las lineas cuando voy al 3er section, a mi me gustaría que en el section 1 se ampliará el primero, en el 2, se encogiera el 1 y ampliara el segundo y así sucesivamente

Tengo ahora mismo esto:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var fps = new FullPageScroll('wrap', {
            mediaQuery: 'screen and (min-width: 800px)',
            goToTopOnLast: false
        });
        fps.onslide = function (e) {
            console.log("Slide " + (e.target.currentSlide + 1) + " of " + e.target.slides.length);
            document.querySelectorAll("#lineas a").forEach((link, index) => {
                if (index === fps.currentSlide) {
                    //añado estilos para indicar que está activa
                    $("#lineas a").addClass('activo');
                } else {
                    //elimino estilos
                    $("#lineas a").removeClass('activo');
                }
            });
            
        }
        document.querySelectorAll('a.top').forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                fps.goToFirstSlide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mueve el contenido de esta "respuesta" a tu pregunta, ya que en realidad es una edición de ella.